# How to copy a file from one repo to another when merged into main ranch?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have 2 files (file_1 and file_2) in 2 different Github repos (repo_1 and repo_2).

Whenever code is merged into file_1 or file_2 of the repos' main branch I want to copy the newly updated file into repo_3

repo_1

- file_1

repo_2

- file_2

repo_3

- file_1
- file_2

How would I do this? Should I look into Github actions or webhooks or some bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I look into Github actions or webhooks

A GitHub Action would be easier to set up and run, as it is executed on the server side (`github.com`), as opposed to a webhook which depends on a local process listening to a JSON payload.

For instance, you would add a `.github/workflows/copy-file1-to-repo3.yml` script which would check if `file_1` is modified and, if it is, copy it to repo3.

The [`actions/changed-files`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changed-files) can help to detect if `file_1` has changed relative to the preceding commit.

```yaml
name: Copy File_1 to Repo_3
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Event `push`: Compare the preceeding commit -> to the current commit of the main branch.
# Event `pull_request`: Compare the last commit of main -> to the current commit of a Pull Request branch.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # windows-latest | macos-latest
    name: Test changed-files
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2 # -> To retrieve the preceding commit.

      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed-files-specific
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v35
        with:
          files: file_1

      - name: Checkout repo_3 if file_1 has changed
        if: steps.changed-files-specific.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: <repo_3_username>/<repo_3_repository>
          ref: main
          path: ./repo_3:

      - name: add commit and push file_1 in repo_3 if file_1 has changed
        if: steps.changed-files-specific.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        run: |
          cp file_1 repo_3/file_1
          cd repo_3
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git add file_1
          git commit -m "Update file_1 from repo_1"
          git push
```